# SQL Queries in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a database of a hospital and "management would like to know how many people got diagnosed with cancer in the last year".

```
CREATE TABLE patients (
ID_patients INTEGER NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE visit(
ID_visit INTEGER NOT NULL,
DATE_visit DATE NOT NULL,
FK_patients INTEGER NOT NULL,
);

  CREATE TABLE Diagnosis(
ID_Diagnosis INTEGER NOT NULL,
FK_disease INTEGER NOT NULL
FK_visit INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE Disease(
ID_disease INTEGER NOT NULL,
Name_disease VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

Now we need to find out: **which patients got diagnosed with cancer last year.**
I used query below to get patients that have visited last year, but I do not know how to target those with cancer ?  I think I should use "VIEW AS" but I'm not sure.

```
SELECT *
FROM Visit
WHERE Date_Visit BETWEEN
(CURRENT_DATE - interval '2' year) AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' YEAR;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As illustrated very nicely by Dank. Here we can use some clean DATE function instead of using INTERVAL. The code looks cleaner this way and also we want data for past year so i  am assuming you need the data for 01/01/2015 to 12/31/2015. Hope below snippet helps.

```
SELECT COUNT(v.FK_patients)
FROM visit v
JOIN Diagnosis d on d.ID_Diagnosis = v.FK_diagnosis --Here is where you connect the tables
WHERE v.Date_Visit BETWEEN
TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12),'YEAR') AND TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YEAR')-1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only need a patient count and you already know how to define cancer, you'll want to use a [JOIN](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefsqlj29840.html) to connect these tables together:

```
SELECT COUNT(v.FK_patients)
FROM visit v
JOIN Diagnosis d on d.ID_Diagnosis = v.FK_diagnosis --Here is where you connect the tables
WHERE v.Date_Visit BETWEEN
      (CURRENT_DATE - interval '2' year) AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' YEAR
AND FK_disease IN(--Your list of cancer ids);
```

Comment: Hey I did a mistake. I put Diagnosis FK in Visit , when it should be FK_VISIT in the Diagnosis

Answer (score 0):

This should be straight forward I guess...:

```
select pa.ID_patients, pa.Name
  from patients pa, visit vi, Diagnosis dia, Disease dis
  where vi.FK_patients = pa.ID_patients
    and dia.ID_Diagnosis = vi.FK_diagnosis
    and dis.ID_disease = dia.FK_disease
    and upper(dis.Name_disease) like '%CANCER%'
```

Just add your date filtering to it and it should show the desired result...

Comment: This is bad syntax... use JOIN

Comment: Yeah, join might do the trick as well. Feel free to retype. ;) quite some time I had to use oracle, but back then the old company used the syntax I used above

Comment: `JOIN` is actually an ANSI standard so it is not specific to just Oracle. Your joins above in the `WHERE` clause will still parse but it is considered an outdated practice these days to join tables this way. It's similar to the old Oracle `(+)` and `(-)` outer join syntax... they came up with a better way of doing it but left the old way around for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Ah, ok. Wasn't sure what oracle supports... as mentioned: we used the outdated syntax for a looong time. I'm familiar with join, but mostly since I moved on to Sql Server. Anyways, thanks for the info.